# How to add a ChartPoint to a DataSet in Chart.js with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, chart.js, powerbi

I want to create a custom visual for powerbi. I'm using chart.js and @types/chart.js. But I cannot add a new ChartPoint to a DataSet of a linechart.

```
let p: ChartPoint = {
                        x: data.timestamp,
                        y: data.value,
                    };
ds.data.push(p);
```

But this cannot compile:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: number[]) => number) | ((...items: ChartPoint[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.

ds type is Chart.ChartDataSets

and ds.data type is Chart.ChartDataSets.data?: number[] | ChartPoint[]

But the push Method signature is:
Array.push(items: (**number & ChartPoint**)[]): number

So I just tried this:

```
                    let a: (number & ChartPoint);
                    a.x = data.timestamp;
                    a.y = data.value;
                    ds.data.push(a);
```

But this cannot compile with the same message:

> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: number[]) => number) | ((...items: ChartPoint[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.

I'm new to Typescript. I don't know how to use the push method and why the push method has a "&" intersection type.

Comment: you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need cast (typescript does not know if it's number or ChartPoint):

```
(ds.data as ChartPoint[]).push(p);
```